# AbstractRoutingDataSource fails after migrating from Hibernate 3 to 4

Tags: spring, hibernate, datasource

I have been using AbstractRoutingDataSource for a while to switch between different databases. The old configuration was Spring 3 and Hibernate 3.5.5. After upgrading Hibernate to 4.2.3, AbstractRoutingDataSource has stopped working (it always retrieves the default database).

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any error trace in the logs?

Comment: What I have found by debugging is that with Hibernate 3, every time the application makes a query on the database (outside a transaction) it invokes the method AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection() that in turn calls  AbstractRoutingDataSource.determineTargetDataSource(). However, after changing to Hibernate 4, it does not invoke any more the method AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection() so it cannot detect the change of the datasource lookupKey

Comment: Add your configuration (including external hibernate configuration files).